# Check if I can remove file

Tags: java, android

I'm opening many types of files using external applications which are available on phone. For security reasons I need to delete this file when the external app does not need it. How can I check if I can safely remove file which are used by third app ?

Answer (score 0):

First of all you need to know which files are used by the third app. You can simply do it by analyzing, (decompiling, if needed) the source code of the application. After knowing all the files used by the third party app you need to check if the third party app actually running or not, because the third party app might use some temporary files, which could be removed when it's no longer open.

If you just want to make a simple cleaner, which cleans the trash of all the apps, then you should simply just remove certain file types (like .tmp files) and remove the cache of the apps.

Comment: In my app I have a list of files (images, pdf, etc..) which needs to be opened. I thought about service which checks in background if selected file can be removed but I don't known when it could be done.

Answer (score 0):

First of all, I think there is no 100% way to determine if file is not used by another application.
I you are asking about files in `sandbox` of other apps, by the way you be able to remove such files because they have granted permissions only for app that they are belong to. So you need root access in this case.

You can remove file like `cache`,`tmp` ... files like system app manager does. If third-party is built correctly this should not affect application.

Also another method is to determine how often file is being used is based on `unix` file timestamps, they are

```
Access - the last time the file was read
Modify - the last time the file was modified (content has been modified)
Change - the last time meta data of the file was changed (e.g. permissions)
```

You can check for example the date when app was installed, than check access time of the file and determine does the application require this file.

But again there is no 100% guarantee that you won't brake an app.